# print the output of 2 commands in 1 file on the same line

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

Thanks for looking at this.

I have a possible simple question, but I wasn't able to find any help so far on the internet.

I have a script that has mainly 2 commands that process output.
But both commands must end up on a single line in a text file that my Nagios system reads and displays. Nagios won't accept the 2nd line to print in the web interface, so I need to have them on 1 line.

The commands.
first a simple print of a file name:

```
ls -tr | tail -n1 > /tmp/output.file
```

this will print the newest file in the folder and writes the name of the file in /tmp/output.file for example: bla-1357135486.xml

The 2nd command is a bit more complex. but finds a field inside that file. and prints that.

```
head -n3 bla-1357135486.xml |  awk -F 'scheduleName' '{ print $2 }' | sed -r 's/^.{1}//' | sed -r 's/.{1}$//'
```

The output of this command look like this:

```
"ChannelName" "scheduleStart=<date>" "scheduleEnd=<date>"
```

I want to have the line in the output.file to look like this:

```
bla-1357135486.xml "ChannelName" "scheduleStart=<date>" "scheduleEnd=<date>"
```

What to add to get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe by storing the output in variables and writing these variables to the file?

```
output1=`ls -tr | tail -n1`
output2=`head -n3 bla-1357135486.xml |  awk -F 'scheduleName' '{ print $2 }' | sed -r 's/^.{1}//' | sed -r 's/.{1}$//'`

echo "$output1 $output2" > /tmp/output.file
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that :) Thanks. That is a good solution...

Answer (score 1):

If you use some text editor try to use just one:

```
awk -F ".scheduleName." '
    NR==1{printf "%s ", FILENAME}
    NR<4{printf "%s ",$2}
    END{print""}' $(ls -t | head -1)
```

I hope is there more than 1 `scheduleName` in line to remove first and last symbols from second field?